# Why can I not use & _ in VBA for strBody?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create an automatic email sender on VBA however for the part of the code I keep getting
Error: Expression error whenever I try to break into a new line.  Specifically I can receiving the error at the '& _' part of my code right after 'Arial>'.

```
Sub demo_sub_email()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim count, i As Integer

count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)))
i = 2

Do While i <= count

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "<BODY style = font-size:12pt; font-family: Arial>" & _
"Cat#" & Sheets("Email Sender").Cells(i, 3) & "/" & "PS#" & Sheets("Email Sender").Cells(i, 4) & " is on " & Sheets("Email Sender").Cells(i, 9) & "."
```

Comment: Works for me....

Comment: Is it your actual code? Make sure you 1) have a space before and after all `&` concat operators, otherwise it parses as an invalid `Long` type hint on the string literal; 2) have fewer than 20 line continuations, because that's about the maximum number of *physical lines* that can be continuated into a single *logical line* of code.

Comment: You also probably want to have a `emailSender As Worksheet` local variable too, so you don't need to pull that sheet from the active workbook's sheets collection every time you need to read a cell value from it

Answer (score 0):

It was spacing I believe! I got it working that day! Thank you to everyone who answered :)